# AMD legacy driver installation failed due to missing kernel headers

Tags: 14.04, drivers, kernel, ati, fglrx

I am trying to install `amd-driver-installer-catalyst-13.1-legacy-linux-x86.x86_64` on Ubuntu 14.04, and failing due missing `/lib/modules/3.13.0-37-generic/build/include/linux/version.h`. I tried to install driver forcefully with no success.

The error in `/usr/share/ati/fglrx-install.log` is:

> Check if system has the tools required for installation. fglrx
>   installation requires that the system have kernel headers. 
>   /lib/modules/3.13.0-37-generic/build/include/linux/version.h cannot be
>   found on this system. fglrx installation is being forced. Installation
>   will proceed without the required tools on the system. Uninstalling
>   any previously installed drivers.
>
> Creating symlink /var/lib/dkms/fglrx/8.97.100.7/source ->
>                    /usr/src/fglrx-8.97.100.7
>
> DKMS: add completed.
>
> Kernel preparation unnecessary for this kernel.  Skipping...
>
> Building module: cleaning build area.... cd
>   /var/lib/dkms/fglrx/8.97.100.7/build; sh make.sh --nohints
>   --uname_r=3.13.0-37-generic --norootcheck....(bad exit status: 1) [Error] Kernel Module : Failed to build fglrx-8.97.100.7 with DKMS
>   [Error] Kernel Module : Removing fglrx-8.97.100.7 from DKMS
>
> ------------------------------ Deleting module version: 8.97.100.7 completely from the DKMS tree.
>   ------------------------------ Done. [Reboot] Kernel Module : update-initramfs

Answer (score 0):

Beginning with 3.7, the uapi sources have changed and this causes issues with some older drivers that can't locate version.h...

Try this:

```
ln -s /usr/src/linux-$(uname -r)/include/generated/uapi/linux/version.h /usr/src/linux-$(uname -r)/include/linux/
```

Comment: As trying to install this driver ruined x-server, It doesn't make sense to try it again ;)